# Move filtered array to another sheet using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with 6 columns that is being updated with a webhook using the doPost function below that works just fine.

I have filtered only the rows where column 5 = 'true' (index [4]), but I would like to move all columns that match this condition of true in column 5 into another sheet and then clear the first sheet leaving only the header rows in the first sheet.

I'm nearly there, but I would appreciate it if anyone has any suggestions to achieve this final step. Thanks for reading...

```
function doPost(e) {

  var jsonString = e.postData.getDataAsString();
  var event = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Import");
  var timeStamp = new Date();
  var time = Utilities.formatDate(timeStamp, "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy, h:mm a");
  var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;

  //Insert the data into the sheet  
  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1).setValue(time);
  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 3).setValue(jsonString);
  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 4).setValue(event.data.amount);
  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 5).setValue(event.data.metadata.is_supplementary);
  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 6).setValue(event.data.reference);
}

function getData() {
  var rows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  var filteredRows = rows.filter(function(row){
    var is_supplementary = row[4];
    if (is_supplementary == true){
      return row;
    }
  })
  Logger.log(filteredRows);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function doPost(e) {
  const jsonString = e.postData.getDataAsString();
  const event = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Import");
  const ts = new Date();
  const time = Utilities.formatDate(ts, "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy, h:mm a");
  const nextRow = sh.getLastRow() + 1;
  sh.getRange(nextRow, 1).setValue(time);
  sh.getRange(nextRow, 3, 1, 4).setValues([[jsonString, event.data.amount, event.data.is_supplementary, event.data.reference]]);//doing last 3 all at once
}

function getData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();//getting active sheet
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().filter(r => r[4]);//test truthiness
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("output");
  osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
  sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
}
```

Comment: This is great; thank you so much, @Cooper. The only issue I can see is that the values copied to the new output sheet don't need to include the header row. Any chance you can adjust this to move the data excluding the header row from the Import sheet?

Comment: They don't but in your code you started with getDataRange() which includes the header line.  I changed it.